# Get apk infromation using c#

Tags: c#, android, apk

I want to get internal names of apk files and I've tried a lot of ways and I've searched a lot. finally this is what I've got :

```
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        proc.Start();
        using (StreamWriter sw = proc.StandardInput)
        {
            foreach (string path in Directories.GetAllFiles(@"E:\apk", "apk"))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("aapt d badging " + "\"" + path + "\"");
                //following line doesn't work because sStandardInput is open
                Debug.WriteLine(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
        // There will be a really huge amount of text (at least 20 line per sw.Writeline) and 
        //it impacts performance so following line is not really what I'm looking for 
        Debug.WriteLine(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
```

`GetAllFiles` is a function that I've created to fetch all apk file full path. This is not final code.
As I've commented it out first `Debug.WriteLine` doesn't work and second one is not a good idea. how should I get output from `proc`?
I have tried running proccess by argument and its awful :)

Comment: apk files are just zip files, you can handle them without invoking external exes. Take a look at the [`ZipFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile.aspx) class.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I know that. There is an xml file named manifest.xml in which there are information I need. but first it's coded and not really easy to decode but main problem is that strings are in a separate file and only thing in manifest file is a reference in that file (and worse, reference is just a number). considering this complexities I guess it's better to use aapt.exe. (all relating softwares do same thing)